# Relationship between two probability measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider an actuarial risk model for a potential loss X with Pareto density $$f(x)=\frac{ac^a}{x^{a+1}}$$ for $x \geq c$, $a>0$, $c>0$..

What is the relationship between $P(A)$ and $PX^{-1}(X(A))$ for a given $A\in F$? Notice that $P(A)$ and $PX^{-1}$ are two probability measures.

I am really confused on $(X(A))$ in $PX^{-1}(X(A))$. I do not know how to interpret this.

I have in my notes that *The probability distribution/law of $X$ is the induced probability measure $\mu = PX^{−1}$ on $R$:*$$\mu(A)=PX^{−1}(A)=P(X^{−1}(A))\equiv P(X \in A)$$ for any $A\subseteq R$.

What I did so far is that I took $X$ as a bijective, since it is invertible. Then I wrote $A=X^{-1}(X(A))$ meaning these measures would be equal. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Random variables are usually not invertible - the sample space can be some massive set, whereas the value of $X$ is a single real number. Therefore, $A \subset X^{-1}(X(A))$ (by basic properties of images and preimages), so the probability of $A$ is less than or equal to the probability of $X^{-1}(X(A))$

Comment: Stating "and the physical loss is described on probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$" without actually saying anything about $\Omega$, $F$, or $P$ doesn't really provide any information. It would be safe to remove that part of the sentence from the question.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Thanks for clarification. How can I show $⊂^{-1}(())$?

Comment: For any $p \in A$, we have that $X(p) \in X(A)$ meaning that $p \in X^{-1}(X(A))$, which means $A \subset X^{-1}(X(A))$. The converse subset relationship doesn't hold unless $X$ is injective.